# Responsive image selecting non retina image, Lighthouse complaining

Tags: html, image, lighthouse

I've a responsive image as follows:

```
<img 
  src="image.jpg1"
  srcset="
    image1.jpg 99w 40h,
    image2.jpg 198w 80h,
    image3.jpg 124w 50h,
    image4.jpg 248w 100h,
    image5.jpg 179w 72h,
    image6.jpg 358w 144h
  " 
  sizes="(min-width: 1280px) 179px, (min-width: 960px) 124px, 99px"
  class="image"
>
```

And then styled as so:

```
.image {
  width: auto
  height: 40px;

  @media (min-width: 960px) {
    height: 50px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1280px) {
    height: 72px;
  }
}
```

Image names have been abridged, but they're all dynamically resized to be the size specified, and their aspect ratio used to ensure the correct height and width.

So, on a large screen (>1280px wide), I'd expect the tag to select `image5.jpg` on standard screens, `image6.jpg` on retina screens.

However, the smaller of the two is getting selected in the browser regardless, while a Lighthouse report selects the larger but still flags this as an issue (despite the image *definitely* measuring 358 x 144):

```
Displays images with inappropriate size

Image natural dimensions should be proportional to the display size and the pixel ratio to maximize image clarity.

URL         Displayed size  Actual size  Expected size
image6.jpg  179 x 72        179 x 72     358 x 144
```

I've run this in Incognito to rule out it being a caching issue, and tested with different images with the same result.

I'm a bit stumped as to why the wrong image is being selected and how to appease Lighthouse. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: your sizes attribute looks incorrect for what you want, you are saying you want 179px at desktop, 124px at tablet and 99px at other sizes. At that point it will not do anything with DPI adjustments so will always serve the 179px image. You need to add ` 2x` next to the images that you want to be used at 2.0 DPI resolution - so " image6.jpg 2x", but then your query wont work. I am not at a computer but a good starting place is https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - thanks a bunch, the `2x` has done the trick. I wasn't aware of it. If you want to pop that in as an answer I'll accept. Appreciate the help here, thank you!